# Loop tables into pl/sql and display number of rows

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have loop for all the tables into db:

```
declare
    V_TABL_NM ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR GET_TABL_LIST IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES )LOOP   
        V_TABL_NM := GET_TABL_LIST.TABLE_NAME;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_TABL_NM);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

How can I sort my result and add number of records for each tables?
I try below but it does not work:

```
declare
    V_TABL_NM ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;

     table_row number;

BEGIN
    FOR GET_TABL_LIST IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES )LOOP   
        V_TABL_NM := GET_TABL_LIST.TABLE_NAME;

        table_row: = select count(*) from TABLE_NAME;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_TABL_NM, table_row);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It is always better to use OWNER while getting count from the table if you are using ALL_TABLES. Also if the statistics are fresh then you can get number of records from NUM_ROWS column in ALL_TABLES

Comment: Do you need the exact counts or will an approximate value do? If you have any significantly large tables the script could take a lot of time to run, which could be massively reduced it you use a `sample` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make a query that way; `TABLE_NAME` has no meaning there (and you're missing to use the cursor name), so you need to build a dynamic SQL and run it to put the value into a variable.
Besides, the `PUT_LINE` does not accept that parameters.
This should work:

```
DECLARE
    table_row                               NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR GET_TABL_LIST IN (  SELECT OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME
                              FROM ALL_TABLES
                          ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' || GET_TABL_LIST.TABLE_NAME INTO table_row;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(GET_TABL_LIST.TABLE_NAME || ' - ' || table_row);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

About the ordering, simply add an `ORDER BY` to the query looping through the tables

This assumes that you have rights to query all the tables listed in `ALL_TABLES` If you simply need to query all the tables of your schema, use `USER_TABLES` instead of `ALL_TABLES`.

Comment: That means that your user can not query all the tables resulting from the query; are you sure you need ALL_TABLES and not USER_TABLES?If the problem is the lack of synonyms, try to use even the owner field and query not TABLE_NAME but OWNER.TABLE_NAME

Comment: but my first query is working ( I can loop all the tables)

Comment: The fact that you can query ALL_TABLES does not mean that you can query all the tables. ALL_TABLES is a view giving you all the tables defined in DB, but you may not have rights to query all these tables with your login user

Comment: simply use USER_TABLES instead of ALL_TABLES

Answer (score 0):

to sort the results add `order by` clausel:

```
FOR GET_TABL_LIST IN 
(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM ALL_TABLES 
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME   --
 )LOOP
```

to count the records use dynamic sql :

```
execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || V_TABL_NM  INTO table_row;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done completely without PL/SQL:

```
select table_name, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as rowcount
from user_tables
order by rowcount;
```

Comment: @4est: which Oracle version are you using. That works fine for me with Oracle 12 and Oracle 11

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production, but probably It not contains all package, any why I will save your code

Answer (score 0):

also I did:

```
select TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS, LAST_ANALYZED
from user_tables
order by 1;
```